# Raising one cell in a table

Tags: tables, raise

[image]

That is, I would like to raise one cell (e).

Currently, the code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\hline
A & B & C & D  \\
\hline
a & b & c & d \\[0.25em]
e & f & g & h \\[0.25em]
  & i & j & k \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I've tried `\raisebox{5pt}{e}`, but this also moves the rest of the row downwards...

Comment: \smash{\raisebox{5pt}{e}} will raise it and hide that fact from the rest of the layout

Comment: Do you want to just raise one or do you want to be a multirow?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: This works! Thanks! If you make it an answer, I'll accept it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   \smash{\raisebox{5pt}{e}}
```

will raise it and hide that fact from the rest of the layout.

Comment: This is not working for a cell where the texts are supposed to wrap to next line.

Comment: @SubhajitPaul no but the question is not a about such cells. in a p column you can use \vspace or other means

Comment: I tried `\vspace`, but it is taking the entire row up. Should I post a separate question for this issue?